# Can not execute CL Command (AS400 command) in PHP script

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

I login to AS400 and go to QSHELL(STRQSH). After that I pasted the following command and run it in QSHELL

```
system "IVIEW/PRTDISTL APPNAME(MYJOBLOG) STMF(TEST_89.PDF) HOLD(*NO)"
```

It works. But when I execute the above command using PHP script as the follow

```
$cmd = "IVIEW/PRTDISTL APPNAME(MYJOBLOG) STMF(TEST_89.PDF) HOLD(*NO)";
$cmd = 'system "' . $cmd . '"';

$output = array();
exec ($cmd, $output , $retVal);

echo "return value code: " . $retVal;
```

It returns error code of 255. Please help me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: Is PHP running on the IBM i or another server?

Comment: yes, PHP running on the IBM i

Answer (score 1):

Try the PHP Toolkit for i5/OS.  There is a older Redbook that describes it: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247327.pdf

An example from there:

```
<HTML>
<?php
/* Connect to server */
$conn = i5_connect("localhost", "PHPUSER", "MYPASSWORD");
if (!$conn)
die("<br>Connection using \"localhost\" with USERID and PASSWORD failed. Error
number =".i5_errno()." msg=".i5_errormsg())."<br>";
else
echo "<br>Connection using \"localhost\" with USERID and PASSWORD OK!<br>\n";
/* Call Retrieve Network Attributes command */
$ret = i5_command("rtvneta", array(), array("sysname" => "sysn", "lclnetid"=>"lclnet"));
if (!$ret) die("<br>rtvneta command failed. errno=".i5_errno()."
msg=".i5_errormsg());
print "<h1><b>Results of \"rtvneta\" command </b></h1><br>" ;
print "System Name : $sysn<br>" ;
print "Local Net ID : $lclnet<br>" ;
/* Close connection */
i5_close($conn);
?>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Because of customer request, the system do not use PHP Zend Tookit for i5/OS. We use QSHELL command (QSH) and execute using exec function of PHP script instead

Answer (score 1):

I see two pontential problems:

1. PHP runs in PASE, not in QShell. Try to manually run your call from QP2TERM.
2. User rights. Make sure QTMHHTTP (or whatever user runs PHP) has the apropriate rights to the program you try to call.

You can check for further information in stdout, which you should have in $output, and your PHP-server joblog as mentioned at [IBM i information center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzalf/rzalfpasesystem.htm) (possibly needing the flag 'system -K').

Comment: I have had inform from admin, it's due to library IVIEW didn’t exist  in library list when RPG program was invoked, thus the files cannot open. Now it works. Thank so much for your support :).

Comment: What does "RPG program" have to do with the question? There doesn't seem to be any "RPG program" referenced unless it's invoked by the `PRTDISTL' command. And if it runs inside the command, then the developers of the command should ensure the presence of the required library. That could probably be done easily enough simply by setting the `PRDLIB()` attribute of the command.